# sql conditional join getting wrong results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

i'm trying to join table Group  on my link table userGroup, to get the groups where user with id 30 is not a member, but i can't seem to get it right.

joining with no conditions returns this

```
SELECT        Groups.ID, Groups.Name, UserGroup.groupID, UserGroup.userID
FROM            Groups LEFT OUTER JOIN  UserGroup ON Groups.ID = UserGroup.groupID
```

```
+----------+------------+-------------------+------------------+
| Group.ID | Group.Name | UserGroup.GroupID | userGroup.UserID |
+----------+------------+-------------------+------------------+
|        1 | g1         | 1                 | 30               |
|        2 | g2         | NULL              | NULL             |
+----------+------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

however when i try to sourt out the row where userID = 30, i'm getting two equally wrong results.
adding the condition in the join part returns both rows but claiming the userGroup.userId is null. i'm suspecting some duplicate rows due to join, but haven't been able to figure out what exactly and how to fix it

```
SELECT        Groups.ID, Groups.Name, UserGroup.groupID, UserGroup.userID
FROM            Groups LEFT OUTER JOIN  UserGroup ON Groups.ID = UserGroup.groupID AND UserGroup.userID <> 30
```

```
+----------+------------+-------------------+------------------+
| Group.ID | Group.Name | UserGroup.GroupID | userGroup.UserID |
+----------+------------+-------------------+------------------+
|        1 | g1         | NULL              | NULL             |
|        2 | g2         | NULL              | NULL             |
+----------+------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

adding the condition to the very end of my statement, returns 0 rows.

```
SELECT Groups.ID, Groups.Name, UserGroup.groupID, UserGroup.userID
FROM  Groups LEFT OUTER JOIN  UserGroup ON Groups.ID = UserGroup.groupID 
WHERE UserGroup.userID <> 30
```

i'm running on an mssql server and using c# SqlCommand to execute the query, but i don't think that's connected to the issue

Comment: query seems `ok` try using `<>`

Comment: UserGroup.userID != 30 this wrong Use UserGroup.userID <> 30

Comment: tried replacing != with <>, no difference, i'm fairly sure that writing != in c# is being translated to <>. I've run several queries with != syntax without errors

Comment: also tried running the queries directly instead through c# code with the visual studio Query tool,  != is automatically replaced with <>

Comment: The problem isn't <> or != qsl server accept both of them!

Comment: agreed, != or <> is not the problem. It should be =. I am looking for groups where userID 30 is a member, and the groups where i do not find that, i want to return. THat is why the left outer join is useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually want to join trying to find where usergroup.userID = 30, not <> 30. From that join you want to return the records where there *is no* such usergroup record.
Try something like this:

```
         SELECT Groups.ID, Groups.Name, UserGroup.groupID, UserGroup.userID
           FROM  Groups 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  UserGroup ON UserGroup.groupID = Groups.ID 
                          AND UserGroup.userID = 30
WHERE UserGroup.UserID IS NULL
```

Comment: Testing on !=30 would still not work.
By testing on != 30, you are actually finding all _other_ members. The presence or absence or userid's != 30 in a group actually tells yuo nothing about the membership of userId 30.

Answer (score 2):

" to get the groups where user with id 30 is not a member"

```
SELECT  *
FROM  Groups g
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UserGroup WHERE groupID = g.iD and userID = 30);
```

seems more natural to me in your case.

Comment: You are selecting all groups where i cannot find a member that is NOT equal to 30.

Comment: The left outer join works as well, matter of taste, but the real problem was indeed that <> or != should be = :)

Comment: Your query and mine do the same now, i think :) Whether you use a join or a subselect is a matter of taste :)

Comment: Yes, sure, they do the same. That is why I wrote "seems more natural to me" ;)

Comment: i upvoted both answers, but marked the one using a join a correct, since this is a sparetime project, where i specifically want to use joins, to get a better understanding of them.

Answer (score 2):

To get the groups where user with id 30 is not a member:

```
SELECT Groups.ID, Groups.Name
FROM Groups 
WHERE Groups.ID NOT IN 
(SELECT UserGroup.GroupID FROM UserGroup WHERE UserGroup.UserID = 30)
```

Comment: this also works, but i specifically want to use join, this is a more of a sparetime learning porject.

Comment: @kOvergaard Ah, ok. Then the query by `oerkelens`is what you want. I was going for the easy readable solution ;)